# Chrome Extension - Tainted canvases may not be exported

Tags: google-chrome-extension, html5-canvas

What permission should be added to manifest of extension, so that convas.toDataURL() from content script don't cause the security error? Thank you.

Comment: I don't think this can be solved with a permission.

Comment: And to help you, please explain in more detail what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I want to get the snapshot of a video.

Comment: Even more detail. Explain, on a high level, your algoritm of capturing, passing and using the data.

Comment: It's quite a big chunk of code. I create video and draw current frame from video to canvas (both operations from content script). The error appears when I try to get the picture by toDataURL().

Comment: Since we have no visibility of your code or your environment, I'll say that in general the server must have a header stating that it allows cross-domain transfers of its content ("Access-Control-Allow-Origin").  This header property can be set to "*" indicating that any destination may use this content or can be set to a specific domain that may use this content.  On the client side you must enable the receipt of cross domain content by setting the "crossOrigin" property to "anonymous".

Comment: crossOrigin doesn't help. Even worse, video doesn't load (No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource).
 About "must have a header". I can easily get a snapshot if I'll do all the operations from background script. But not so fast unfortunately. So, I believe, there's a solution, or it's a bug.

Comment: There's no way to help you...we have no info about code or environment. Sorry :-<

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a permission that the video `src` will match. Your content script may be running at site.com, but the video may be hosted at sitecdn.com -- so you could add `"*://*.sitecdn.com/*"` to `permissions`

Comment: I tried <all_urls>, and it doesn't work. As I have already said in the comments I can do the same operations from underground script, which I cannot do without proper permission.

Comment: I don't see any reference to an "underground" script. If you can provide a simplified reproducible example, we can probably help you. Otherwise, all that I can say is that the limited case that you explain works for me in production code. I had a hiccup when developing it and the problem was exactly my answer.